# Nginx proxy with Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I try to setup new app using Docker and Nginx proxy. My setup work nice with only 1 ports shared via docker-compose.yml. But i need to share 2 ports between container and my host.

With 2 ports, my proxy return an error 502 :

```
version: '3'

services:
  foody:
    build: ./config/docker
    container_name: my_app
    environment:
      #- NODE_ENV=production
      - LOCAL_USER_ID=$USER_ID
      - LOCAL_GROUP_ID=$GROUP_ID
      - PGID=1000
      - PUID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp.${SITE_URL},api-myapp.${SITE_URL}
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=3339,3340
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=myapp.${SITE_URL}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${MAILER_DEFAUT_SENDER_ADDRESS}
    ports:
      - 3339:3000
      - 3340:1337 // Work if i comment or remove this line
    volumes:
      - .:/app

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

I'm not really understand why my proxy work only if i share 1 ports on my docker-compose file ... :/

From [nginx-proxy documentation](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) :

`Multiple Ports
If your container exposes multiple ports, nginx-proxy will default to the service running on port 80. If you need to specify a different port, you can set a VIRTUAL_PORT env var to select a different one. If your container only exposes one port and it has a VIRTUAL_HOST env var set, that port will be selected.`

My logs from container :

```
nginx.1    | 2019/12/19 06:33:41 [error] 2227#2227: *151845 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xx, server: myapp.mydomain.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://myapp.mydomain.com/favicon.ico", host: "myapp.mydomain.com", referrer: "https://myapp.mydomain.com/"
```

Anyone have already fix this simple use case ?

Thank you !

Comment: What do the logs tell you about this error?

Comment: Hi :) I've edit my first post with this information

Comment: you mean `3340:3000` right ?

Comment: Nop, `3339:3000` is client app and `3340:1337` is api.

Comment: `foody` container is running on both port `3000` and `1337` ?

Comment: Yep. I've add more information about nginx-proxy and multiple port on my first post.

Comment: Just as a thought: the documentation speaks about "the port", not "the ports" (multiple ones) to be set using `VIRTUAL_PORT`...

Comment: Yep, but same result if i set only 1 port, 1 domain but exposes 2 ports :(

Comment: I've same result if i try with 2 sevices